# holeMenuProgram.cpp:38:1 Error: Expected Primary-Expression before '}' token

Tags: c++, switch-statement, label

I am creating a menu using switch cases but when I got to filter out unavailable choices using a do-while statement I am getting an odd error. Could I get some insight on what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance as I am a new programmer. I am aware the case switches have nothing in them but this shouldn't stop it from compiling correctly.

```
//Programmer: Lane Floyd  Date: 2/17/2020
//File: holeMenuProgram.cpp
//Description: 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int menuChoice;  //User input 1-4 for menu choice.

do
{
  // Below is the menu.
  cout << "       Menu        " << endl;
  cout << "       ----        " << endl;
  cout << "1.  Enter a number    " << endl;
  cout << "2.  Power the number    " << endl;
  cout << "3.  Cube root of the number    " <<endl;
  cout << "4.  Quit"  <<endl;

  cout << "Input Choice: \r";
  cin >> menuChoice;

} while (menuChoice != 1 || menuChoice != 0);


switch(menuChoice)
{
  case 1:

  case 2:

  case 3:

  case 4:
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to put a `break;` statement after each `case #`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A label must precede a statement. You could write for example

```
switch(menuChoice)
{
  case 1:

  case 2:

  case 3:

  case 4:
  ; 
}
```

placing a null statement before the closing brace in the switch statement.

Or to make the code more readable you could insert at least one break statement like

```
switch(menuChoice)
{
  case 1:

  case 2:

  case 3:

  case 4:
      break; 
}
```